# prestodb: simple IF condition to create a column

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

I'm very new to Presto and SQL, and struggling with something that might be basic.

I have a simple table: id and number_of_customers

I'd like to do a select that computes a third column and puts certain flags depending on number_of_customers, for e.g., if num > 1000, the computed column would have A, if it's > 10000 then B etc - I intend to have 4-5 such flags.

```
id    num
 1    200000
 2    40000
```

and select result being

```
1  200000 A
2  40000 B
```

Can't figure out how to do this. Examples I see for IF and CASE are too complicated.

Edit: this is what I have:

```
SELECT name, count as num
case
when num < 1000 then 'A'
when num > 10000 then 'B'
else 'X'
end
FROM dbs
limit 10
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a standard use case for [`CASE` expressions](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/conditional.html#case). Depending on actual flags it can look like:

```sql
-- sample
with dataset(id, num) as (
    values (1, 200000),
    (2, 40000)
)

-- query
select *,
       case
           when num < 1000 then 'A'
           when num <= 40000 then 'B'
           else 'X'
           end
from dataset;
```

Output:

| id | num | _col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 200000 | X |
| 2 | 40000 | B |

Note that order of conditions matters, if there are multiple conditions that match the first will be used.

Comment: Hi, is this on Presto? I have select a, b as x, case (just as you have)... but get a syntax error (this is on AWS Athena) saying only one sql statement is allowed.  Guess I have to tinker around some more.

Comment: I updated above with my sample code which doesn't work.

Comment: @Gerry yes, this is presto and it does work.

Comment: @Gerry your sql at least misses comma after  `as num`

Comment: added it, now it says num cannot be resolved. :(

Comment: figured it out! I was trying to do a condition on an aggregate. Now I get it, thank you!